Product of a squence involving square roots of natural numbers
I want to see what is the value of this sequence:
$$q_k = \prod_{n=1}^k \frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n+1}-1}.$$
Note that $\frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n+1}-1}= \frac{\sqrt{n+1}+1}{\sqrt{n}}$, which helps us to see that this $(q_k)_k$ is increasing, since every incoming factor are $>1$.
By the way, by drawing some graphs I am convinced that $q_k$ grows pretty fast with $k^\alpha = \mathcal{o}(q_k)$ for $a>1$, at least for $a$ not too big.

The factor's natural logarithm is asymptotic to $1/\sqrt{n}$, so $\ln q_k\sim2\sqrt{k}$.

Expanding as a series we have
$$
\frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n+1}-1} = 1 + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} + \frac{1}{2n} - \frac{1}{8n^2} + O\left(n^{-3}\right).
$$
Hence
$$
\log \left(\frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n+1}-1}\right)
= \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} - \frac{1}{6n^{3/2}} + O\left(n^{-5/2}\right).
$$
Hence
$$
\log q_k = \sum_{n=1}^k\log \left(\frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n+1}-1}\right)
= 2\sqrt{k} + \frac{1}{3\sqrt{k}} + O\left(k^{-3/2}\right).
$$
Hence
$$
q_k = \exp\left(2\sqrt{k} + \frac{1}{3\sqrt{k}} \right)
\left(1 +  O\left(k^{-3/2}\right)\right).
$$

If you consider
$$S_k=\sum_{n=1}^k \log\left(\frac{\sqrt{n+1}+1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)$$  since we know that
$$\int\log\left(\frac{\sqrt{n+1}+1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)\,dn=\sqrt{n+1}+n \log
   \left(\frac{\sqrt{n+1}+1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)$$ use the simplest form of Euler-MacLaurin summation to obtain
$$S_k=2\sqrt k+C+\frac{5}{6 \sqrt{k}}+O\left(\frac{1}{k^{3/2}}\right)$$ For this level of expansion $C\sim -\frac{137}{75}$.
Exponentiate to get the product.
Trying for $k=100$, the truncated formula will give
$$\exp\Big( \frac{5477}{300} \Big)\sim 8.48730\times 10^7$$ to be compared to the "exact" $8.48717\times 10^7$
